# proper handling of casting when instantiating a specific Class<T>

Tags: java, generics

I have a function that looks (in principle) like this

```
public <T extends Listener> T createListener(Class<T> clazz) {
  if (clazz == SpecificListener.class) {
    return (T) new SpecificListener();
  }
  // more instantiations here
}
```

with SpecificListener being an implementation of interface Listener. This code works, but the return statement does an unchecked conversion to T.

Is there a better way to write this without doing the unchecked conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The checked conversion would be `clazz.cast(new SpecificListener())`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [Class#cast(Object obj)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

```
public <T extends Listener> T createListener(Class<T> clazz) {
  if (clazz == SpecificListener.class) {
    return clazz.cast(new SpecificListener());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the listeners your could instantiate do provide a nullary constructor, you could *simply* try:

```
public <T extends Listener> T createListener(Class<T> clazz)
throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return clazz.newInstance();
}
```